# Discord.py как добавить реакцию не нажимая на нее

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Сейчас имеется следующий код:

```py
@bot.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    msg = discord.Embed(title="Здравствуйте :)", description='Выберите, что вы хотите сделать:' '\n', color=0x00ff00)
    send_msg = await ctx.send(embed=msg)
    str(send_msg)                                  
    await send_msg.add_reaction("")
    await send_msg.add_reaction("")


@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = await bot.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
    await channel.send("Message")
```

Проблема в том что бот при добавлении реакции автоматически на нее нажимает и активирует ивент нажатия.
Как можно это поправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А как по другому? Даже когда пользователь добавляет реакцию она уже считается нажатою. Просто проверяйте кто нажал кнопку если это не бот то исполняем последующий код, если да то ничего.

```
@bot.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    msg = discord.Embed(title="Здравствуйте :)", description='Выберите, что вы хотите сделать:' '\n', color=0x00ff00)
    send_msg = await ctx.send(embed=msg)
    str(send_msg)                                  
    await send_msg.add_reaction("")
    await send_msg.add_reaction("")


@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.member.bot is False:
        channel = await bot.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
        await channel.send("Message")
```

Да и я думаю что не надо сообщение переводит в строку оно и без этого прикрепляет реакции

`str(send_msg)`